# After Delete or Update or Insert Refresh Table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Does anybody know how I can refresh data in the table after insert, delete and update operations? I have a simple table:

```
create table EV_JOURNAL (EVENT_TO_TASK_ID NUMBER(3)
NOT NULL Check(EVENT_TO_TASK_ID>0), EVENT_TIME TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL);
```

// table created
I found some info about triggers and has written an after insert, delete and update trigger:

```
    create or replace 
TRIGGER AFT_INS_UPD_DEL_TRIG
   AFTER Insert or Delete or Update ON EV_JOURNAL   
   For Each Row
  DECLARE 
  BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO EV_JOURNAL(EVENT_TO_TASK_ID,EVENT_TIME)
   VALUES(:NEW.EVENT_TO_TASK_ID, :NEW.EVENT_TIME); 
  END AFT_INS_UPD_DEL_TRIG;
```

But when I'm trying to insert some data to the table, something like this:

```
Insert into ev_journal (event_time,event_to_task_id) values(systimestamp,2);
```

I have the following errors:
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table EV_JOURNAL is mutating, trigger/function may not see it;
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger;
Could someone help me in this situation? I need only to refresh table and that's all, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Code from my c# app where I need to use refreshed data from the given table:

```
public static List<EventTrigger> FillEventTriggerList (List<EventTrigger> list)
        {            
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection (connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open ();
                string sqlText = "Select * From EV_JOURNAL";
                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand (sqlText, connection);
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader ();
                while (reader.Read ())
                {                               
                    list.Add (new EventTrigger (int.Parse(reader [ "EVENT_TO_TASK_ID" ].ToString()),(DateTime)(reader [ "EVENT_TIME" ])));
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

So, when I let's say delete some rows from EV_JOURNAL, after this Select query I get old data which must be already deleted but it becomes so only after I click refresh table in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense -- you're detecting changes to a table and trying to respond by inserting the same rows into the same table.

Perhaps you can explain what you mean by "refreshing" a table.

Edit: You are not clicking refresh in the database, you are clicking refresh in some tool that is accessing the database. The data change has been made, but whatever tool you are using then has to be told, via this click, to go and read the new version.

Comment: By refreshing table I mean just do the same action as by clicking refresh in the database. I need to get data from table from my c# app. But when I affect the table by inserting, updating, deleting something in my Select query I have old results from table. I'll add the code to my question now.

Comment: Maybe you have not committed your change. But the deeper issue here is that you are not understanding that when you have performed an insert, update or delete against the database table, the data change has happened. You do not need to do anything else except issue a commit (if that's not done automatically) to allow other sessions to see that change.